# why I can not use tables with 'foreign key'?

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, android-sqlite

When I create 2 tables, without foreign key everything works fine, but when I add a foreign key, my app doesn't create the tables.

Please help me.

```
//table1
private static final String CREATE_TABLE1 = "create table "
        + TABLE_MEMBER + "(" + MIEMBRO_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + MIEMBRO_NOMBRE + " TEXT);";
//table2
private static final String CREATE_TABLE2= "create table "
        +EJERCICIOS_TABLA+"("+EJERCICIO_ID
        +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        +EJERCICIO_NOMBRE+" TEXT);";
//table3
private static final String CREATE_TABLE3= "create table "
        +REGISTRO_TABLA+"("
        +ID_REG+"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        +ID_U+" INTEGER, "
        +ID_E+" INTEGER, "
        +RM_MAX+" REAL, "

        +" FOREIGN KEY (" +ID_U+ ") REFERENCES "+TABLE_MEMBER+" ("+ MIEMBRO_ID +") ON DELETE CASCADE,"
        +" FOREIGN KEY ("+ ID_E +") REFERENCES "+EJERCICIOS_TABLA+" ("+ EJERCICIO_ID +")ON DELETE CASCADE;";
```

And here the onCreate() method:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        // Enable foreign key constraints
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE1);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE2);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE3);
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+EJERCICIOS_TABLA+" ("+EJERCICIO_NOMBRE+") VALUES('Sentadilla') ");

    db.execSQL("insert into "+TABLE_MEMBER+" ("+MIEMBRO_NOMBRE+") values('Pedro')");
```

when I create Table1 and Table2 all is ok, but when I create the table3 fail.

Comment: What is the error (exception) message?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing ) after the last CASCADE.

It should look like this:

```
//table3
private static final String CREATE_TABLE3= "create table "
    +REGISTRO_TABLA+"("
    +ID_REG+"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
    +ID_U+" INTEGER, "
    +ID_E+" INTEGER, "
    +RM_MAX+" REAL, "

    +" FOREIGN KEY (" +ID_U+ ") REFERENCES "+TABLE_MEMBER+" ("+ MIEMBRO_ID +") ON DELETE CASCADE,"
    +" FOREIGN KEY ("+ ID_E +") REFERENCES "+EJERCICIOS_TABLA+" ("+ EJERCICIO_ID +")ON DELETE CASCADE);";
```

Comment: It's been a while since I last worked with SQLite so I can't remember if it matters, but you have a double space in table 3 before the first foreign key

Comment: Since I can only comment on my own answers so far, I'll post it here: Try to put the if sentence where you enable foreign keys after you have created the three tables, but before the insert statements.

Comment: Okey I fix the problem. miss space before INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT in table 3. thanks all

Comment: But i still got problems, because foreign keys doesn't work...Probably I should enable it but i don't now how

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is correct:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
        // Enable foreign key constraints
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }
```

I read that foreign keys are always off and I added this to the onCreate method.